# Flatten/Simplify an array of arrays containing objects to be an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, flatten

So is have this "beautiful" multidimensional array:

```
array 
  0 => 
    array 
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)
          public 'name' => string 'some name'
          public 'model' => string 'some model'
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)
          public 'name' => string 'some name'
          public 'model' => string 'some model'
  1 => 
    array 
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)
          public 'name' => string 'some name'
          public 'model' => string 'some model'
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)
          public 'name' => string 'some name'
          public 'model' => string 'some model'

and so on
```

I removed middle arrays to get one with loops (and converted object to array):

```
foreach ($items as $x) {
    foreach ($x as $y) {
        $item[] = (array) $y;
    }
}
```

Result is:

```
array 
  0 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'some name'
      'model' => string 'some model'
  1 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'some name'
      'model' => string 'some model'
  2 => ...
  3 => ...
  etc.
```

It gets job done (makes array with 4 arrays in it), but I am wondering what would be more clean way to do this? Yes and looping 1000+ arrays must not be the best idea. I am not looking for exact code, just idea.

Comment: You can also use `array_walk_recursive()` if you prefer that syntax.  It's the same algorithm in the backend, though.

Comment: @Sam No, `array_walk_recursive()` only visits leafnodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($items as $x) {
    foreach ($x as $y) {
        $item[] = (array) $y;
    }
}
```

The solution you have is the best because then you won't have conflicting keys if you use `array_merge()`, and the time complexity is `O(n)` which is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not better or faster (not tested) but alternates:

```
$result = array_map('get_object_vars', call_user_func_array('array_merge', $items));
```

Or:

```
foreach(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $items) as $o) {
    $result[] = (array)$o;
}
```